# How to make create multiple modals on one page with React-Responsive-Modal

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have recently installed the React-Responsive-Modal library and it does work however, I would like to create multiple modals on one page. with each button, I click opening up its own unique modal.

I tried naming the states differently and passing those different states as props to the buttons and modals but it still doesn't seem to work.

here is the code:

```
 const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
 const [open2, setOpen2] = useState(false);


  const onOpenModal = () => setOpen(true);
  const onCloseModal = () => setOpen(false);

  const onOpenModal2 = () => setOpen(true);
  const onCloseModal2 = () => setOpen(false);



 return (
<div className='cards'>

<div>
  <button onClick={onOpenModal}>Open modal</button>
  <Modal open={open} onClose={onCloseModal} center>
    <h2>Simple centered modal</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam
      pulvinar risus non risus hendrerit venenatis. Pellentesque sit amet
      hendrerit risus, sed porttitor quam.
    </p>
  </Modal>
</div>

 <div>
  <button onClick={onOpenModal2}>Open modal</button>
  <Modal open={open2} onClose={onCloseModal2} center>
    <h2>Simple centered modal</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam
      pulvinar risus non risus hendrerit venenatis. Pellentesque sit amet
      hendrerit risus, sed porttitor quam.
    </p>
  </Modal>
</div>

</div>
```

);

Also, when I use this method, only the first modal puts up even if I click the second button

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in this line

```
const onOpenModal2 = () => setOpen(true);
```

It should be

```
const onOpenModal2 = () => setOpen2(true);
```

So that's why the second one didn't open.
Also you have the same error for onCloseModal2